# Variable parameters in xcolor package

Tags: macros, color

This doesn't work and I'm having trouble thinking of a minimum *working* example, but I'd like to do something like this where I have a *parameter* to a command as a variable:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{126,169,105}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{26,69,15}

\newcommand{\ColorVariable1}{mycolor1}
% or
\DeclareRobustCommand{\RobustColorVariable1}{mycolor1}
```

to allow me to have several places in the body of my document where I do things like this:

```
\textcolor{\ColorVariable1}{Some text in a variable color}
```

and I can change the colors of all those colored text portions with one fell swoop by assigning a new color (as below) to the *variable* rather than replacing mycolor1 with mycolor2 with an editor global search and replace in all the places in the text as I'm doing now.

```
\newcommand{\ColorVariable1}{mycolor2}
```

I know that I can do something similar (but not for parameters) in the body of the document:

```
\def\somestring{Replace \somestring with this text.}
```

And something also similar with commands, but this doesn't seem to work for parameters:

```
\newcommand{name}[num][default]{definition}
```

Is there any way to do something like this in LaTeX?

Comment: Control sequence names can't contain digits (at least not in an easy and robust way).

Comment: You know `\colorlet` of package `xcolor`? Then you can do `\colorlet{colorvariable1}{mycolor1}` and using `\textcolor{colorvariable1}{...}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `\colorlet` was exactly what I was looking for. If you'll write this as an answer then I'll gladly accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `xcolor` provides `\colorlet`. Defining a "color variable", using it and reassigning the color can be seen in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{126,169,105}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{26,69,15}

\colorlet{ColorVariable1}{mycolor1}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{ColorVariable1}{Some text in a variable color}

\verb|\colorlet{ColorVariable1}{mycolor2}|
\colorlet{ColorVariable1}{mycolor2}

\textcolor{ColorVariable1}{The color of the variable color can also be
changed.}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

The following seems to be a more suitable usage where you define `\ColorVariable` to take two arguments - the first being a colour number and the second being the text you want coloured:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\definecolor{mycolor1}{RGB}{126,169,105}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{RGB}{26,69,15}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ColorVariable}[2]{%
  \textcolor{\ifnum#1>2 black\else mycolor#1\fi}{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ColorVariable{1}{Some text in a variable colour}.

Some text in a variable \ColorVariable{2}{colour}.

Some \ColorVariable{3}{text} in a \ColorVariable{1}{variable} \ColorVariable{2}{colour}.
\end{document}
```

A test is built in to set the colour to `black` if the number specified is larger that the total `X` number of colours defined as `mycolorX`.

Comment: Thank you @Werner although I may have written my question poorly (or else I may not understand your answer). It looks like in your answer, if I wrote a document with most of the text in black and many various pieces of text all colored green, for example, and then later decided that I wanted them all blue instead, then I would need to do an editor-based global search-and-replace of your `\ColorVariable{3}` with `\ColorVariable{1}` which is like what I was doing before. I was looking for a way to make the color I assign to text a variable that I could use everywhere & change only once if des'd.

Comment: You can redefine the colour as you wish later (as in [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133495/5764)). So, if `mycolor2` should change *mid-document* to `mycolor3`, then that's possible with a single `\colorlet` command and you can leave everything else unchanged.